# how to implement countdown timer in milliseconds to answer a question. If timer runs out, loop breaks

Tags: c, time

Okay, so I am working on a project right now, and the project is to create a game. Here is the concept below:

```
Please press any key to begin!
Press the ‘h’ key!
You have 2500 milliseconds to respond!
Press the ‘c’ key!
You have 2400 milliseconds to respond!
Press the ‘k’ key!
You have 2300 milliseconds to respond!
Wrong key! :(
You lose!
You made it through 3 rounds!
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-                               Prototypes                                   -
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char random1 ();
int cmpChar(char rand2, char user1);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-                               Implementation                               -
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL)); /* This will ensure a random game each time. */
    
    time_t cdt;
    time(&cdt);
    ctime(&cdt);
    printf("%s\n", ctime(&cdt));
    
    char ans, randChar;
    int gameCont = 1;
    int score = 0;
    
    printf("This is a Bop-It Game!\n");
    printf("\nPress any key to start\n");
    getch();
    
    int i = 2600;
    while(gameCont == 1){
        randChar = random1();
        printf("press the '%c' key!\n", randChar);
    
        ans = getch();
        gameCont = cmpChar(randChar, ans);
        if (gameCont == 1){
            score++;
        
        i -= 100;
        printf("You have %d milliseconds to respond!\n", i);
        }
    }
    printf("Your score was %d!\n", score);
    return 0;
} 

char random1 (){
    char randInput;
    randInput = (rand()%(122-90)+90);
    return randInput;
}
int cmpChar(char rand2, char user1){
    if (user1 == rand2){
        return 1;
    }
    if (user1 != rand2){
    printf("That is incorrect\n");}
    else{
        return 0;

    }
}
```

If you can see, I implemented a code that kind of mimics the countdown millisecond thing, but it doesnt actually use a timer, it just uses a loop and print statements.
Im on windows OS, and am trying to use #include <sys/time.h> to create a way to implement a timer, and also have it decrease by 100 milliseconds after each iteration.
If you can help with the whole implementation, great, otherwise just a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have to use multithreading for that. Take a look at the `Sleep` function and the `_beginthread` function. You can start a child thread to execute `getch` while waiting with `Sleep` in the main thread.